# Minimize cost of recursive pairwise sums: how to prove the greedy solution works?

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, greedy-algorithms

The problem is in [this other question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/101031/minimizing-sum-of-recursive-pairwise-sums).

Why does this always work? It's not clear to me how one would use induction.

For $n = 3$, a quick calculation shows it works, however, I don't think it generalizes well.

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each summing approach can be represented by a binary tree: the leaves represent the original elements and each internal node (including the root) represents the result element of the addition of the elements represented by its two children. For example,

```
Input: [1, 5, 3, 7]
Adding 1 and 3 together (Cost 1+3 = 4)
State: [5, 7, 4]
Adding 4 and 5 together (Cost 4+5 = 9)
State: [7, 9]
Adding 7 and 9 together (Cost 7+9 = 16)
State: [16]

Total cost: 4 + 9 + 16 = 29
```

... can be regarded as the following tree:

```
      16
     /  \
    9    \
   / \    \
  4   \    \
 / \   \    \
1   3   5    7
```

Then we rewrite the cost of each addition as the sum of original elements. For example, the costs in the example above are:

```
4 = 1+3
9 = 4+5 = 1+3+5
16 = 7+9 = 1+3+5+7

Total cost: 4 + 9 + 16 = 29
```

We can see each number corresponding to a leaf is contributed to the total cost in the additions corresponding to its ascendants. For a leaf $e$, If we denote by $h(e)$ the height of $e$, and by $f(e)$ the number corresponding to $e$, then the total cost is exactly $\sum_{e\ :\ \text{leaves}}f(e)\cdot h(e)$.

Note each tree represents a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) of the leaves. In the example above, the tree represents the prefix code:

```
1: 000
3: 001
5: 01
7: 1
```

If we regard $f(e)$ as the frequency of $e$, then $\sum_{e\ :\ \text{leaves}}f(e)\cdot h(e)$ is the average length of the code, which is optimized by [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). Note the answer in your link describes exactly how Huffman coding works.